# How to sum two words from two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
ingredient=[{'product_id': 234, 'product_name':'meat', 'price':3.5}, {'product_id':324, 'product_name':'pickles', 'price':1.0}, {'product_id':146, 'product_name':'roll', 'price':3.0}, {'product_id':289, 'product_name':'chees', 'price':2.5}]
products=[{'product_id':634, 'product_name':'hamburger', 'price':3.5, 'ingredients':[{'product_id':234, 'quantity':1}, {'product_id':324, 'quantity':1}, {'product_id':146, 'quantity':1}]}, {'product_id':777,'product_name':'cheesburger','ingredients':[{'product_id':234, 'quantity':1}, {'product_id':324, 'quantity':1}, {'product_id':146, 'quantity':1}, {'product_id':289, 'quantity':1}]}]
cart=[{'product_id':634, 'quantity':2}, {'product_id':777, 'quantity':4}]

summary_price=0
for item in cart:
    summary_price += item['price'] * item['quantity']
    print('Summary price is:', summary_price)
```

I have a new dictionary which will be my cart and I would like without entering the price, how much does a Burger cost, for example I wanna import price from products and I would like to sum up this cart, is it possible?

Comment: You could `filter` the  `products` list so that only products where `product["product_id] == item["product_id"]` remain and then get their prices so sum then up. That seems unnecessary, you could refactor your  `products` list to a dict: `{product_id: {name: "hamburger", price: 4.5}}`

Answer (score 2):

Making a dictionary of the products (or their prices) by ID will make this easier:

```
prices = {product["product_id"]: product["price"] for product in products}
summary_price = sum(prices[item["product_id"]] * item["quantity"] for item in cart)
```